# Issue with jQuery and auto-resizing textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this TextAreaExpander jQuery function working, but I'm having one little issue with it.

When the textarea is very large, removing text from the bottom of it with the backspace or delete buttons causes the focus to move to the top of the textarea, and so the cursor gets moved off the screen.  It makes it very jarring to edit large sections of text.

How do I get this function to auto-resize the textarea, but without jumping around and hiding the cursor in that situation?

```js
(function($) {
    // jQuery plugin definition
    $.fn.TextAreaExpander = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {
        var hCheck = !($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera);
        // resize a textarea
        function ResizeTextarea(e) {
            // event or initialize element?
            e = e.target || e;
            // find content length and box width
            var vlen = e.value.length, ewidth = e.offsetWidth;
            if (vlen != e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth) {
                if (hCheck && (vlen < e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth)) e.style.height = '0px';
                var h = Math.max(e.expandMin, Math.min(e.scrollHeight, e.expandMax));
                e.style.overflow = (e.scrollHeight > h ? 'auto' : 'hidden');
                e.style.height = h + 'px';
                e.valLength = vlen;
                e.boxWidth = ewidth;
            }
            return true;
        };
        // initialize
        this.each(function() {
            // is a textarea?
            if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'textarea') return;
            // set height restrictions
            var p = this.className.match(/expand(\d+)\-*(\d+)*/i);
            this.expandMin = minHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[1], 10) : 0);
            this.expandMax = maxHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[2], 10) : 99999);
            // initial resize
            ResizeTextarea(this);
            // zero vertical padding and add events
            if (!this.Initialized) {
                this.Initialized = true;
                $(this).css('padding-top', 0).css('padding-bottom', 0);
                $(this).bind('keyup', ResizeTextarea).bind('focus', ResizeTextarea);
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
// initialize all expanding textareas
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('textarea[class*=expand]').TextAreaExpander();
});
```

You can see the issue here by deleting text from the very bottom of the textarea:
http://jsfiddle.net/BmwCe/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding a better function to use instead of the one above.  It doesn't seem to have any of the problems of the other one.

You can find the details on it here:
[Auto resizing textarea link down jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045018/auto-resizing-textarea-link-down-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Could this help?

Has anyone considered contenteditable? No messing around with scrolling, and the only JS I like about it is if you plan on saving the data on blur... and apparently, it's compatible on all of the popular browsers : http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable

Just style it to look like a text box, and it autosizes... Make its min-height and line-height the preferred text height and have at it.

What's cool about this approach is that you can save  and  tags on some of the browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/gbutiri/v31o8xfo/

```
<style>
.autoheight {
    min-height: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('blur','.autoheight',function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    // The text is here. Do whatever you want with it.
    console.log($this.html());
});

</script>
<div class="autoheight contenteditable" contenteditable="true">Mickey <b>Mouse</b></div>
```