# how to give auto scroll to textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have written an HTML form with a text area, text box and a button. Whatever I have typed on the textbox will be appended to the textarea when the button is clicked. Now, my problem is when the text area is completely filled, the newly arriving text appears at the bottom and I have to scroll down manually to view this text. Is there any method in javascript to make the arriving text to be visible always without scrolling down...Please help

Comment: This can be achieved through javascript or jquery your browser doesn't knows that you want to view this text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a textarea to keep scrolled to the bottom when updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373081/how-to-have-a-textarea-to-keep-scrolled-to-the-bottom-when-updated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure if this is what you want but have a look this:

http://jsfiddle.net/yV76p/

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

textarea.onkeyup = function(evt) {
    this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight;
}
```

You can find the details on it here: [Auto resizing textarea link down jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045018/auto-resizing-textarea-link-down-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

This example increases the size of the textarea as the content text is added;

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImpressiveWebs/fGNNT/1885/)

**Javascript**

```
var txt = $('#comments'),
    hiddenDiv = $(document.createElement('div')),
    content = null;

txt.addClass('txtstuff');
hiddenDiv.addClass('hiddendiv common');

$('body').append(hiddenDiv);

txt.on('input', function () {

    content = $(this).val();

    content = content.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    hiddenDiv.html(content + '<br class="lbr">');

    $(this).css('height', hiddenDiv.height());

});

txt.trigger('input');
```

**CSS**

```
body {
     margin: 20px;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

textarea {
    color: #444;
    padding: 5px;
}

.txtstuff {
    resize: none; /* remove this if you want the user to be able to resize it in modern browsers */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.hiddendiv {
    display: none;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word; /* future version of deprecated 'word-wrap' */
}

/* the styles for 'commmon' are applied to both the textarea and the hidden clone */
/* these must be the same for both */
.common {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 50px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.lbr {
    line-height: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For having auto scrolling feature for textarea add this piece of code at the end of where ever you are trying to attend the content from textbox:

```
 var console = $('#area');
 console.scrollTop(
 console[0].scrollHeight - console.height());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ds345/433Pp/2/)

Hope this helps :)